# How to hide pop up view on previous page when pressing back button on swift

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, back-button, navigationcontroller

I have this kind of flow page :

Setting Page --> Enter Password --> Go to Page X

So in setting page, in order to go to page X, I have to enter a password using pop up view.
When I'm in page X and i want to go back to previous page, I go to enter password pop up view, instead of the setting page.
How do I skip that page?

My pop up view code is something like this :

```
let btn = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PopUpView") as! PopUpView
        addChild(btn)
        btn.view.frame = view.frame
        view.addSubview(btn.view)
        btn.didMove(toParent: self)
```

I'm fairly new here, any help will be appreciated.

Thankyou.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the settings view controller's present function to open the popup.

```
//In your settings view

func openPopup() {
    let btn = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PopUpView") as! PopUpView
    self.present(btn, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

When the user clicks ok, call dismiss on your popup view and use the closure to initiate the page opening to X

```
//In your 'PopUpView' On the OK button action of your popup

func didTouchOk() {
    self.dismiss(animated: true) { [weak self] in
        guard let self = self else { return }
            
        //Put your open page X code here
        let XView = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "XViewController") as! XView
        self.present(XView, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

if you are using navigationController:

Declare a protocol in your PopUpView

```
protocol popupDelegate: class {
    func userDidTouchOkInPopup()
}
```

create a weak var in your PopUpView

```
weak var delegate: popupDelegate? = nil
```

In your settings viewcontroller:

Assign delegate to popup before pushing

```
func openPopup() {
    let btn = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: 
    "PopUpView") as! PopUpView
    btn.delegate = self
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(btn, animated: true)
}
```

Implement an extension for this protocol

```
extension SettingsViewController:  popupDelegate {

    func userDidTouchOkInPopup() {
        self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
        let XView = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: 
        "XViewController") as! XView
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(XView, animated: true)

    }

}
```

Modify the Ok action in your PopUpView

```
//In your 'PopUpView' On the OK button action of your popup

func didTouchOk() {
    self.delegate?.userDidTouchOkInPopup()
}
```

Comment: how do I keep using `pushViewController` when i'm moving to page X? I'm not suppose to use modals in this part. how do I do that?

Comment: @AldoSugiarto I edited the answer, please check if it helps

Answer (score 1):

If you are in navigationController hierarchy, use `navigationController.popToViewController` to go to the specific ViewController.
In `ViewDidLoad`, hide the present backButton and create a new One and associate action with it.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
let newBackButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Back", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(backButtonFunction))
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = newBackButton
}
```

Inside `backButtonFunction`, you can put the code

```
@objc func backButtonFunction(){
  if let navController = self.navigationController {                                
    for controller in navController.viewControllers {
       if controller is SettingsViewController { // Change name of ViewController accordingly
          navController.popToViewController(controller, animated:true)
        break
     }
  }
}
}
```

Comment: this is a good one, but where should I put this code?
it's like I need to put this action in back button of navigation controller
if i put it inside `viewDidLoad()` , the page will go back when I just entered page X